# Regex: extract before, after character

Tags: javascript, regex

given the following string

```
stringData= "goal01=4 goal02=2 goal06=3 goal09=1 goal12=5 goal13=2 goal14=4 planet=52 people=48 Inclusion=4 HealthWellness=2 SustainableInfrastructure=4 ResponsibleConsumption=9 Environment=2"
```

I need a regex to parse the following two variants

```
stringColumns = stringData(regex that //fetch before '=' and add ',' to string i.e goal01,goal02,planet etc..) 
stringValues= stringData(regex that //fetch after '=' and same as above 4,2,3,52, etc..)
```

as I need them split in order to construct a sql insert statement such as

```
sqlSyntax = "INSERT INTO [table] ("'+stringColumns+'") VALUES ("'+stringValues+'")"
```

I tried  `^([^=])+` and it only matched the first `goal01` what do I need to fetch all the remainings?

https://regex101.com/r/QZgfPh/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do not need regex. Simply split with spaces then with equal signs and pull out the necessary characters:

```js
var stringData = "goal01=4 goal02=2 goal06=3 goal09=1 goal12=5 goal13=2 goal14=4 planet=52 people=48 Inclusion=4 HealthWellness=2 SustainableInfrastructure=4 ResponsibleConsumption=9 Environment=2";

var dataArray = stringData.split(" ")
var stringColumns = dataArray.map(item => item.split("=")[0]).join(",");
var stringValues = dataArray.map(item => item.split("=")[1]).join(",");

console.log(stringColumns);
console.log(stringValues);
```

Here is the ES5 equivalent, in case you cannot use ES6 arrow functions:

```js
var stringData = "goal01=4 goal02=2 goal06=3 goal09=1 goal12=5 goal13=2 goal14=4 planet=52 people=48 Inclusion=4 HealthWellness=2 SustainableInfrastructure=4 ResponsibleConsumption=9 Environment=2";

var dataArray = stringData.split(" ")
var stringColumns = dataArray.map(function(item) {
  return item.split("=")[0];
}).join(",");
var stringValues = dataArray.map(function(item) {
  return item.split("=")[1];
}).join(",");;

console.log(stringColumns);
console.log(stringValues);
```

However, if you explicitly want to do it using regex, you can do this:

```js
var stringData = "goal01=4 goal02=2 goal06=3 goal09=1 goal12=5 goal13=2 goal14=4 planet=52 people=48 Inclusion=4 HealthWellness=2 SustainableInfrastructure=4 ResponsibleConsumption=9 Environment=2";

var stringColumns = stringData.match(/[A-Za-z0-9]+(?==)/g).join(",");
var stringValues = stringData.match(/(?<==)[0-9]+/g).join(",");

console.log(stringColumns);
console.log(stringValues);
```

Comment: The first pattern [can be](https://regex101.com/r/AhOlJK/1) `(?<=\s*)[A-Za-z0-9!]+(?==)` without making the character class non greedy because it can not cross matching `=` (which by itself does not have to be escaped) The second pattern [can be](https://regex101.com/r/7Ytbjr/1) `(?<==)[A-Za-z0-9!]+(?=\s|$)` as using `(?=\s*)` is always true as the whitspace chars is optional.

Comment: Yes, good point! I will edit accordingly.

Comment: @WaisKamal Nice, as it is now you can remove `(?=\s*)` as it is always true (it says, if we are looking at optional whitespace chars) and remove the escape from `\=`

Comment: You're right. Even the second `[A-Za-z0-9]` is not necessary since the OP is only looking for numbers.

Comment: but if you run the snipet of the regex, the formating of the result is different to the split and I need the split format, also my application is not liking the map array code, but it works on jsfiddler  `JST-310000 Error while compiling script '_webApp_APP208__preview' line 198: syntax error (line='var stringCols = dataArray.map(item => item.split('=')[0]).join(',');
' token='> item.split('=')[0]).join(',');
').
SCR-160032 JavaScript: error while compiling script '_webApp_APP208__preview'.   `

Comment: I executed the code using my browser's rendering engine and it seems to work, as when I do it with my application's javascript rendering engine, it fails, just wondering if there is an unsopported function or method that my app rendering engine cant interpret, is there another way of performing the same split but using different code.

Comment: What environment is the map code not working in?

Comment: i can't tell for sure, from some docs (Adobe Campaign Classic) Javascript implementation is Spider Monkey, so it is probably ECMAScript 5 (2009) standard)

Comment: ECMAScript 5 does not support arrow functions (they were added in ECMAScript 6) so that is probably the issue. Try using ordinary functions and see if it works.

Comment: which is the arrow function in this line `dataArray.map(item => item.split('=')[0]).join(',');` the map one?

Comment: `item => ... join(',')` This is the arrow function. I will add the ES5 equivalent to the answer